# Ошибка компиляций при попытке вывести метод

Tags: java

```
class cityTour extends Tourism {

public cityTour() {
parisTour.ayazhanRoute;
parisTour.averageCost("Париж");
}
public ayazhanRoute(){
  System.out.println("Cобор Нотр-Дам - Площадь Отель-де-Виль - Башня Сен-Жак - Лувр - Сад Тюильри - Площадь Согласия - Елисейские поля - Площадь Трокадеро - Эйфелева башня");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
  cityTour parisTour = new cityTour();
}

// класс Tourism

class Tourism {

public void averageCost(String city) {

System.out.println("Средняя стоимость однодневного тура по городу "+ city + " 300 евро");
}
}
```

Comment: Добавьте лог ошибки

Comment: 1) В сообщении об ошибке указывается причина. Читайте его. 2) Изучайте синтаксис `java` и учитесь самостоятельно понимать, что можно писать, а что нельзя. 3) Если, несмотря на все ваши знания, всё-таки не можете понять причину ошибки, приводите в вопросе текст сообщения об ошибке и указывайте, на какую строку кода ругается компилятор. Вопросы такого рода здесь не приветствуются и ваш вопрос, скорее всего, закроют, а вам минусов наставят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если метод ayazhanRoute() не возвращает ни какого значения то это должно быть отмечено void, да и сам вызов метода нуждается в скобках. Вот поправленый код

```
class cityTour extends Tourism {

    public cityTour() {
        parisTour.ayazhanRoute();
        parisTour.averageCost("Париж");
    }
    public void ayazhanRoute(){
        System.out.println("Cобор Нотр-Дам - Площадь Отель-де-Виль - Башня Сен-Жак - Лувр - Сад Тюильри - Площадь Согласия - Елисейские поля - Площадь Трокадеро - Эйфелева башня");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    cityTour parisTour = new cityTour();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

код, без синт. ошибок, используйте нормальное IDEA и не-будут таких ошибок

```
class cityTour extends Tourism {

    public cityTour() {
        parisTour.ayazhanRoute();
        parisTour.averageCost("Париж");
    }
    public void ayazhanRoute(){
        System.out.println("Cобор Нотр-Дам - Площадь Отель-де-Виль - Башня Сен-Жак - Лувр - Сад Тюильри - Площадь Согласия - Елисейские поля - Площадь Трокадеро - Эйфелева башня");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    cityTour parisTour = new cityTour();
}

// класс Tourism

class Tourism {

    public void averageCost(String city) {

        System.out.println("Средняя стоимость однодневного тура по городу "+ city + " 300 евро");
    }
}
```